# Effects of expertise on mental condition?

Tags: health-psychology, self, expertise

As [a search](https://www.frontiersin.org/search/journal/psychology?query=expertise&tab=top-results&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.frontiersin.org%2Fjournals%2Fpsychology%23) on *Frontiers in Psychology* shows, there a different articles and research topics about the topic of being an expert.

But is there any literature or research about the effects of being an expertise on the mental health of a person or the state of self-actualization ?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  Your question is a little unclear to me.  Do you mean effects of being an expert on an expert's mental condition?  Expert in what subject? What mental condition are you thinking of?  Are you talking about pre-existing mental health issues improving of declining as the person is becoming an expert?